# Laravel proper procedure for using javascript.

Tags: javascript, node.js, laravel

I'm trying to properly use js inside of laravel. From what I understand all js gets concatenated into one app.js file inside public after running "npm run dev."

This is how I have set things up so far: 
In resources/js I have created a custom.js file where I put all my custom js functions:

```
function myFunction() {
    console.log("clicked fff");              
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".www").click(function(){
        $(".qqq").hide();
    });
});
```

I have also required this in resources/js/app.js:

```
/**
 * First we will load all of this project's JavaScript dependencies which
 * includes Vue and other libraries. It is a great starting point when
 * building robust, powerful web applications using Vue and Laravel.
 */

require('./bootstrap');
require('./custom');
window.Jquery = require('jquery');
window.Vue = require('vue');

/**
 * The following block of code may be used to automatically register your
 * Vue components. It will recursively scan this directory for the Vue
 * components and automatically register them with their "basename".
 *
 * Eg. ./components/ExampleComponent.vue -> <example-component></example-component>
 */

Vue.component('example-component', require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue'));

// const files = require.context('./', true, /\.vue$/i)

// files.keys().map(key => {
//     return Vue.component(_.last(key.split('/')).split('.')[0], files(key))
// })

/**
 * Next, we will create a fresh Vue application instance and attach it to
 * the page. Then, you may begin adding components to this application
 * or customize the JavaScript scaffolding to fit your unique needs.
 */

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});
```

Then my master layout looks like this:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en" dir="ltr">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
        <title>Website Name</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}">
        <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
      </head>
      <body>
      @include('inc.navbar')
      <p class="qqq">jgkfjkj</p>
      <button class="www">Click me to hide paragraphs</button>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
<!--More stuff below-->
```

Finally, I ran "npm run dev."
The  jQuery stuff runs fine but the myFunction() does not. I get the following error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined
>       at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**why this doesn't work**

All your js code gets bundled in one big js file. To prevent naming collision woth other js code its wrapped in a function.

So when you define a function (like `myFunction`) it's only available in that the function that the bundler wraps it in. (This is through the nature of javascripts function scope)

**solutions**

One way to fix this problem is to explicitly assign it to the global scope (which is the window object).

```
window.myFunction = function() { alert('quick and dirty') }
```

A more programmatic way is to add an eventListener to the onClick event and then call your function, like so:

```
document.getElementById('yourButtonId').addEventListener('click', myFunction)
```